# Nodejs net multiple data events

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I have a nodejs backend working as a proxy between an angular app using websockets and a snapserver via tcp socket.

I am using rxjs to wrap the nodejs net socket as a Subject.
For some reason the 'data' event of my tcp socket is called once more each message is sent.

After some request I get a `(node:21209) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit`

```
const log = require('./logger').init('SNAPCAST');
const utils = require('./utils');
const Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');
const net = require('net');

const createSubject = () => {

  return Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {

    const socketConnection = net.connect({port: 1705}, () => {

      const socketObservable = Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
        socketConnection.on('data', (data) => {

          if(data) {
            String(data.toString().trim()).split('\n').forEach((line) => {

              if(line) {
                observer.next(JSON.parse(line));
              }

            });
          }

        });
        socketConnection.on('error', (err) => observer.error(err));
        socketConnection.on('close', () => observer.complete());
      });

      const socketObserver = {
        next: (data) => {
          if (!socketConnection.destroyed) {
            socketConnection.write(`${JSON.stringify(data)}\r\n`);
          }
        }
      };

      const socket = Rx.Subject.create(socketObserver, socketObservable);

      observer.next(socket);
      observer.complete();

    });

    socketConnection.on('error', (err) => {
      observer.error(err);
    });

  });

};

module.exports = () => {

  return Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {

    createSubject().subscribe((socket) => {

      const sendRequest = (message) => {

        message.id = message.id || utils.UUID();
        message.jsonrpc = message.jsonrpc || '2.0';

        socket.next(message);

        return socket.filter((response) => {
          return response.id === message.id;
        }).first();

      };

      observer.next({
        proxyRequest: (request) => {
          return sendRequest(request);
        }
      });

      observer.complete();

    }, (err) => {
      observer.error(err);
    });

  });


};
```

Comment: Try to simplify your question // code sample so you get a better change of it being answered.

Answer (score 0):

Leaking event emitters can be caused by not removing listeners. This seems to be the case in your code example. I would suggest you modify your code as follows:

```
Observable.create(obs => {
  function handleSocketData = data => {};

  socketConnection.addEventListener('data', handleSocketData);

  //unsubscribe function
  return () => {
    socketConnection.removeEventListener('data', handleSocketData);    
  }
});
```

This would result in your eventListeners being removed when the observable completes/errors/unsubscribes.

Above code can be simplified even further by using [`Observable.fromEvent(socketConnection, 'data')`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromEvent) which abstracts away the add/remove event listener logic.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. My guess was that the `sendRequest ` function causes the problem with the .filter() and added .first() to automatically unsubscribe after the first match.

Answer (score -1):

That is just how TCP works, it's a *stream* of data. So application-level messages could arrive in one or multiple `'data'` events. You have to be ready to handle either situation.

Comment: I know that tcp chunks can arrive in multipe parts because one frame does not fit. Thats not the problem here. My data event is fired multiple times with the whole data. The json fits in one frame.